# M2Eclipse force latest plugins/dependencies

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I created a a new simple project using the "maven-archetype-webapp" version = RELEASE (It didn't show the version number but just said "RELEASE").

What I noticed is that though I have only Java SE 8 JDK and JRE, still, the default source and target versions for this archetype was "1.5" as shown in the "JRE System Library". 
I then also noticed that in the Effective POM, the version for maven-compiler-plugin was 2.5.1, while the latest release version of 3.2 is available on mvnrepository. Similarly, POM has the junit version of 3.8.1 while 4.12 release version is available.

I was able to edit the POM and upgraded versions for these plugins and then I was able to compile it for source/target of Java 8. Great!

However, every new project that I create using "maven-archetype-webapp" archetype still chooses older versions. Is there a way to tell M2E to always include the most up-to-date release versions for the plug-ins and the external jars?

I tried using the "updatePolicy" = always in "releases" but it didn't upgrade the plugins to the latest versions?

I checked the M2E version in the Help/About/Installation Details. It is 1.5, which is the latest version on M2E website too.

Totally, blocked! Any suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: Today, without using the Eclipse/m2e, I created a project using the "mvn archetype:generate" command. I selected the same archetype "maven-archetype-quickstart". It created the project but the junit is still 3.8.1. What do I need to do in order to ask Maven to always pick up the latest release versions of all the dependencies and plugins from the central/local repository?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple because all standard archetypes use one parent, where all version a set by default. For example, you could see here - http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-bundles/maven-archetype-webapp/dependency-convergence.html - that by default it always will use JUnit 3.8.

This could be solved, by manually updating pom.xml that you use.